# How to install packages in aurelia skeleton-typescript-aspnetcore

Tags: aurelia

I'm following the "Contact Manager" introduction in Aurelia HUB, using the aspnetcore typescript skeleton. Thus, my solution havn't been set up using `au new` from the Aurelia CLI.

For the last bit of the tutorial, nprogress must be installed, and I'm struggling with that part. I've `npm install nprogress --save` and nprogress has been added to package.json. I've also installed the typing from Definitely Typed. So far so good.

Now the tutorial wants me to add nprogress to the `vendor-bundle.js` bundle, which is part of the CLI installation. So I don't have that bundle.

How do I go on from here? I've tried adding nprogress to the `bundles.js` file, but the reference is still missing when I run the app. There's also a config.js file that has som mappings, which I believe are used by aurelia `require`. I've tried adding nprogress here as well, but no dice.

All these configuration files are somewhat confusing. How do I get a package running? Thanks.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I've been told that the skeleton does not permit you to add additional components.  Try with the CLI or Webpack.

Comment: 'jspm install nprogress' did the trick :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jspm install nprogress` did the trick.

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks for sharing your solution.